# Returning an array of structures from C program to NodeJS/Javascript

Tags: node.js, c

We have device driver written in C and frontend in NodeJS.  We need to return an array of structure from the C function to the Javascript function.

The C function can return a single pointer, but for the array of structures, we are returning a double pointer(a pointer to a pointer) and that is not accessible to the JS program

Has anyone encountered(and resolved) a similar issue?

Comment: Can you add some more detail? What is the communication channel between the C and the NodeJS components?
Do you mean a linux device driver, with a `/dev/...` virtual file?
Or is it a C library embedded inside node.js?

Comment: Why return a double pointer? I see no need for that.

Comment: We need to return device parameters/attributes(about 7 in number) via the driver(which is in C) to the calling function(in JavaScript). The number of devices is dynamic - it can be 5 or 25 or 40. So we thought that returning an array of structures. Is there a better way to implement this(e.g. using some other datastructure with a single pointer or something like that)?